# Match two arrays in a document in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In a document of a collection, I have two fields `student` and `mcqs` which are of type array.

Eg.

```
student: [{

    "id": 2024,
    "answer": "C",
    "bookMarked": false,
    "mcqId": 408041
}, {

    "id": 2025,
    "answer": "B",
    "bookMarked": false,
    "mcqId": 408042
}, {

    "id": 2026,
    "answer": "C",
    "bookMarked": false,
    "mcqId": 408043
}]
```

```
mcq: [{

        "id": 408041,
        "answer": "C",
        "mcqSubject": {
            "id": 289,
            "name": "Mathematics",
            "description": "Mathematics"
        }
    }, {

        "id": 408042,
        "answer": "C",
        "mcqSubject": {
            "id": 289,
            "name": "Mathematics",
            "description": "Mathematics"
        }
    },
    {

        "id": 408043,
        "answer": "C",
        "mcqSubject": {
            "id": 289,
            "name": "Chemistry",
            "description": "Chemistry"
        }
    }
]
```

I want to get the count of all correct answers that were made for each of the subjects.

To do so, I think we should match on 'mcq.id' and 'student.mcqId' checking the 'answer' in both arrays.

Ideal output:

```
{
    "subjects": [{
            "name": "Mathematics",
            "correctCount": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "Chemistry",
            "correctCount": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What you had tried ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use MongoDB aggregation pipeline here

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$studentMcqs"
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$mcqs"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      mcqs: 1,
      studentMcqs: 1,
      mcq_comp_value: {
        $cmp: [
          "$mcqs.id",
          "$studentMcqs.mcqId"
        ]
      },
      ans_comp_value: {
        $cmp: [
          "$mcqs.answer",
          "$studentMcqs.answer"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      mcq_comp_value: {
        $eq: 0
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$mcqs.mcqSubject.name",
      correctCount: {
        $sum: {
          $cond: [
            {
              $eq: [
                "$ans_comp_value",
                0
              ]
            },
            1,
            0
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

and can find the working example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XXipHSH7Qno)